# Could not find module 'shelljs'

Tags: node.js, cordova

I have an Error when I run an Apache Cordova project from Visual Studio 2015 as below.

```
Error   BLD401  Error : BLD00401 : Could not find module 'shelljs'. Please Go to Tools --> Options --> Tools for Apache Cordova --> Cordova Tools --> Clear Cordova Cache and try building again.
```

I tried to install shelljs grobally

> npm install -g shelljs

But still not working.

Should I convert it to PhoneGap project and work on other IDEs?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

I found the solution that some reason the [-g] to install globally wasn't working. So what I did was installing the shelljs command in the project location as below.

> Path To The Project\platforms\android\cordova

and then install "shelljs" at the location

> npm install shelljs

Hope this help someone has the same issue.

Comment: If [-g] is not working, does anyone know of a version of npm where this is fixed? This answer worked for me in 2.7.4

Answer (score 4):

For me worked setting first the `NODE_PATH`:

```
export NODE_PATH=$(npm root -g)
npm install -g shelljs
```

Answer (score 1):

I use macOS and I had the same problem within one of the microservices we work on.

This error can persist even when we run the command npm run shelljs.

So, What I had to do was:

- Delete node_modules folder in the project: rm -r -f node_modules
- run npm install again
- run npm build
- finally: npm run start:dev

Problem solved succesfully ! :)